# subtract 2 to the text size of a textview in java

Tags: android, android-actionbar, textview, text-size

I have an action bar with a settings menu. On it it says Smaller Text which I then want to get the textsize and subtract 2 from whatever the text size is currently. I have the following code which for some reason just makes the text bigger.

```
    @Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.small) {
        TextView english = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.English);

        english.setTextSize(english.getTextSize()-2);

        return true;
    }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You need to know the current display metrics, especially the density, of the device in order to make the correct size adjustment. Tablets with very high resolution will have higher pixel density. By default, the  unit used when
you call getTextSize is SP or Scaled Pixels. So, if you don't consider the density
and call the setTextSize by passing it with the current text size, it will not work. The code below is the proper way of doing it.

```
DisplayMetrics metrics;
metrics = getApplicationContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
float fTextSize = english.getTextSize()/metrics.density;
english.setTextSize(fTextSize-2);
```

Comment: Generally avoid code-only answers.  Consider adding a `description` that helps to explain your code.  Thanks

Comment: That looks much better.  Welcome to SO by the way!